# Storing and Retrieving a list in IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, memory, .net-core

I am currently doing the following to store a list in the IMemoryCache:

```
_memoryCache.Set("PriceList", horsepricelist);
```

And accessing it/returning data:

```cs
public PriceResponse.PriceForEntry GetPriceListEntry(DateTime meetingDate, int courseId, int raceNumber, string horseCode)
{
    var pricelist = _memoryCache.Get("PriceList");
    var dateprefix = "/Date(" + meetingDate.Ticks.ToString() + ")/";

    return ((IEnumerable)pricelist).Cast<PriceResponse.PriceForEntry>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.meetingDate == dateprefix &&
                                                                                            x.courseId == courseId &&
                                                                                            x.raceNumber == raceNumber &&
                                                                                            x.horseCode == horseCode);
}
```

Return a list without the horsecode:

```cs
        public List<PriceResponse.PriceForEntry> GetPriceList(DateTime meetingDate, int courseId, int raceNumber, bool? ShowAll)
        {
           var pricelist = _memoryCache.Get<List<PriceResponse.PriceForEntry>>("PriceList");
           var dateprefix = "/Date(" + meetingDate.Ticks.ToString() + ")/";

           return pricelist.Where(x => x.meetingDate == dateprefix && x.courseId == courseId && x.raceNumber == raceNumber).ToList();
        }
```

The viewmodel structure of the list that in held in the cache:

```cs
public class PriceResponse
{
    public class PriceForEntry
    {
        public string meetingDate { get; set; }
        public int courseId { get; set; }
        public int raceNumber { get; set; }
        public string horseCode { get; set; }
        public List<Bookmakerprice> bookmakerPrices { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bookmakerprice
    {
        public int bookmakerId { get; set; }
        public string bookmakerName { get; set; }
        public string selectionId { get; set; }
        public string fractionalOdds { get; set; }
        public float decimalOdds { get; set; }
        public string bookmakerRaceid { get; set; } //This is the event Id.
        public string bookmakerMarketId { get; set; } //Market Id.
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to get values such as setting various keys and values in the cache to get an entry rather than converting the object back to the list and looping through it?

Comment: you can use helpers to do so.

Comment: Are there any available ones? I have not seen many

Comment: because you are combining couple of logic to fetch data from your list then putting them in separate key/value would not solve any problem. Actually the way that you store is fine and as you are using the IMemoryCache you dont have the problem of performance. its better you elaborate what do you mean by better way ? converting back the list all the time is the problem ? if yes why it is a problem does it make you app slow ? or there are other problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. this one and some other helpers are in this [github repository](https://github.com/EronSolutions/EronHelpers).

```cs
using System.Web.Caching;

namespace System.Web
{
    public static class CacheExtensions
    {
        static object _sync = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes a method and stores the result in cache using the given cache key.  If the data already exists in cache, it returns the data
        /// and doesn't execute the method.  Thread safe, although the method parameter isn't guaranteed to be thread safe.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="cache">Cache from HttpContext.  If null, method is executed directly.</param>
        /// <param name="cacheKey">Each method has it's own isolated set of cache items, so cacheKeys won't overlap across methods.</param>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        /// <param name="expirationSeconds">Lifetime of cache items, in seconds</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T Data<T>(this Cache cache, string cacheKey, int expirationSeconds, Func<T> method)
        {
            var data = cache == null ? default(T) : (T)cache[cacheKey];
            if (data == null)
            {
                data = method();

                if (expirationSeconds > 0 && data != null)
                {
                    lock (_sync)
                    {
                        cache.Insert(cacheKey, data, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expirationSeconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                    }
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So instead of adding each entry to thr list and setting the whole list inside the cache, basically, add each entry in the cache with it's own key? so the key could be like: "meetingDate_courseId_raceNumber_horseNumber"

Comment: that would be an custom implementation. it's considered a generic way of setting and getting the data from/to cache memory

Comment: If i set each entry into the cache with it's key as above, I would be able to return an entry fine. But what about If I want a list of entrys but without the horsecode? Updated my post with the other GetPriceList function.